# Node.JS url rewriting

Tags: javascript, node.js

i come to you because i'm stuck for rewrite my url in javascript.
For example when user make a request for deposit page , my url looks like '/member/deposit' but i just want '/deposit'. i'm using a MVC architecture.

index.js // Where i define all routes file

```js
const
    homeRoute = require('./home'),
    memberRoute = require('./member');

function init(server) {
    server.get('*', function (req, res, next) {
        res.locals.user = req.user || null;
        return next();
    });
    server.use('/', homeRoute);  
    server.use('/member', memberRoute);
}
module.exports = {
    init: init
};
```

router member.js // Where i define all member routes

```js
const
    express = require('express'),
    memberController = require('../controllers/member');

let router = express.Router();

router.get('/*', function(req, res, next){
    if (req.session.user && (req.session.user.role == "member"))
        next();
    else
        res.redirect('/login');
});

router.get('/', memberController.deposit);
router.get('/deposit', memberController.deposit);
router.get('/withdraw', memberController.withdraw);

module.exports = router;
```

controller member.js // where all code is executed before rendering

```js
function deposit(req,res){
    res.render('member/deposit',{
        title:'Deposit'
    });
}

function withdraw(req,res){
    res.render('member/withdraw',{
        title:'Withdraw'
    });
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, i've not find response on stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

It can be use this way:

```
server.use('/', homeRoute);  
server.use('/', memberRoute);
```

As long as the link in homeRoute and memberRoute have no duplication.

Or

The complete rewrite of url can be done as in the following link:
https://gist.github.com/ramonfritsch/06893c1c561d670687a9aee3bbc4e9c7

Comment: Omg the solution was so easy, why I didn't try this earlier. Thank's a lot , works fine

Comment: u r welcome. u may vote or mark this answer correct as well. thanks.

Comment: i marked this answer correct, but seems i don't have enough reputation for being displayed